# What is the next step in downloading Code::Blocks?

Tags: ppa

I'm running 64 bit Ubuntu v. 14.04, and am trying to set up Code::Blocks(a compiler for c++) on my computer. Through the codeblocks website, I made my way to [this launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable). In terminal, I executed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable
```

and it worked fine, processed and imported the public key, and then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which also worked. What is the next step that I need to take to get code::blocks running? I read up on PPAs on [the Launchpad website](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware), but was unable to find any instructions on what to do next.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The next step is to install the `codeblocks` package: `sudo apt-get install codeblocks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Code::Blocks is available in **Ubuntu Standard repositories**, therefore you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Or Download it from software Center

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup>*</sup>But this is **not** the latest version. (13.12 is available here)

> To get the latest version:

(16.01)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

**NOTE** : There are several plug-ins you might need as per your requirements:

<sup>**codeblocks-common** : common files for Code::Blocks IDE</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-contrib** : contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-contrib-common** : common files for the contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-contrib-dbg** : Debugging libraries for the Code::Blocks contrib plugins</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-dbg** : Code::Blocks debugging libraries</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-dev** : Code::Blocks development libraries (SDK)</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-headers** : Code::Blocks development headers (SDK)</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-libwxcontrib0** : Code::Blocks shared libraries for wxContribItems</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev** : Code::Blocks development libraries for wxContribItems</sup>

<sup>**codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers** : Code::Blocks development headers for wxContribItems</sup>

<sup>**libcodeblocks0** : Code::Blocks shared libraries</sup>

<sup>**libwxsmithlib0** : wxSmith shared library (Code::Blocks plugin for RAD GUI editing)</sup>

<sup>**libwxsmithlib0-dev** : wxSmith development metapackage</sup>

<sup>**wxsmith-dev** : wxSmith development files (libraries)</sup>

<sup>**wxsmith-headers** : wxSmith development files (headers)</sup>

To install any of these : `sudo apt-get install package-name`

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly the answer that I was looking for, very helpful.

Comment: @Matt If this is the answer you were looking for, please click the check mark on the left to thank the user and allow others to see this was the right answer.